# Calculate median as separate column in SQL Server : error in result

Tags: sql, sql-server, median

I have a table `TERADATA_Q4_Temp` & after adding some filters, here is how the rows look:

**Query:**

```
select * 
from [TERADATA_Q4_Temp]
where CUST_ID = '100008666' and TRXN_TYPE = '2001' and MONTH = '11'
```

Results:

```
CUST_ID ACCT_NO TRXN_TYPE   CURRENCY TYPE   TRXN_DATE   MONTH   Total Amount    txn count
100008666   9335945808  2001        MXP 2015-11-17  11  5000    1
100008666   9335945808  2001        MXP 2015-11-23  11  20000   1
100008666   9335945808  2001        MXP 2015-11-09  11  5000    1
```

Now, I am trying to calculate median on the column 'txn count' using the below query & I get the correct results:

Query:

```
SELECT  
    AVG(1.0E * [Total Amount]) as 'MEDIAN_DAILY_AMT'
FROM    
    (SELECT  
         [Total Amount],
         2 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Total Amount]) - COUNT(*) OVER () AS y
     FROM   
         [TERADATA_Q4_Temp]
     WHERE
         CUST_ID = '100008666' and TRXN_TYPE = '2001' and MONTH = '11') AS d
WHERE   
    y BETWEEN 0 AND 2
```

Result:

```
MEDIAN_DAILY_AMT
5000
```

But, when I try to calculate the median as a separate column field, I am getting an error. Can you please check my below query to see where I am going wrong -

Query:

```
SELECT 
    [CUST_ID], [ACCT_NO], [TRXN_TYPE], [CURRENCY TYPE], [MONTH], 
    (SELECT  
         AVG(1.0E * [Total Amount])
     FROM    
         (SELECT  
              [Total Amount],
              2 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Total Amount]) - COUNT(*) OVER () AS y
          FROM   
              [TERADATA_Q4_Temp]) AS d
     WHERE   
         y BETWEEN 0 AND 2) as 'MEDIAN_DAILY_AMT'
FROM 
    [TERADATA_Q4_Temp]
WHERE
    CUST_ID = '100008666' and TRXN_TYPE = '2001' and MONTH = '11'
GROUP BY 
    [CUST_ID], [ACCT_NO], [TRXN_TYPE], [CURRENCY TYPE], [MONTH]
```

Results:

```
CUST_ID ACCT_NO TRXN_TYPE   CURRENCY TYPE   MONTH   MEDIAN_DAILY_AMT
100008666   9335945808  2001        MXP 11  10573.51
```

As, you can see I am getting the median as 10573.51 instead of 5000.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version that may help.  It was originally used for rolling Mean/Median/Mode

Notice that I added another ID with some random balances.

You may also notice, if there is NO MODE, we display the range (low/high)

For the Median.  If there is an even number of observations, we take the average of the middle two.

```
Declare @Table table (ID varchar(50),Measure decimal(9,2))
Insert into @Table (ID,Measure) values
('100008666',5000),
('100008666',20000),
('100008666',5000),
('AnotherID',25000),
('AnotherID',1800),
('AnotherID',1000),
('AnotherID',2200)

;with cteBase as (Select *,RowNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By Measure) From  @Table),
      cteMean as (Select ID,Mean=Avg(Measure),Rows=Count(*) From cteBase Group By ID),
      cteMedn as (Select ID,MedRow1=ceiling(Rows/2.0),MedRow2=ceiling((Rows+1)/2.0) From cteMean),
      cteMode as (Select ID,Mode=Measure,ModeHits=count(*),ModeRowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order By Count(*) Desc) From cteBase Group By ID,Measure)
 Select A.ID
       ,MinVal  = min(Measure)
       ,MaxVal  = max(Measure)
       ,Mean    = max(B.Mean)
       ,Median  = isnull(Avg(IIF(RowNr between MedRow1 and MedRow2,Measure,null)),avg(A.Measure)) 
       ,ModeR1  = isnull(max(IIf(ModeHits>1,D.Mode,null)),min(Measure))
       ,ModeR2  = isnull(max(IIf(ModeHits>1,D.Mode,null)),max(Measure))
       ,StdDev  = Stdev(Measure)
  From  cteBase A
  Join  cteMean B on (A.ID=B.ID)
  Join  cteMedn C on (A.ID=C.ID)
  Join  cteMode D on (A.ID=D.ID and ModeRowNr=1)
  Group By A.ID
  Order By A.ID
```

Returns

```
ID          MinVal  MaxVal      Mean            Median      ModeR1    ModeR2    StdDev
100008666   5000.00 20000.00    10000.000000    5000.000000 5000.00   5000.00   8660.25403784439
AnotherID   1000.00 25000.00    7500.000000     2000.000000 1000.00   25000.00  11677.328461596
```

Comment: I should add.  if you have a large data-set, see another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622599/using-overpartition-by-when-calculating-median-moving-average-unit-cost/38625420#38625420

Comment: Updated answer to remove the cteExpand -- not need for this purpose